# Open link in external browser from blackberry10 with cordova

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I am trying to open a link in the native browser or other external browser from my blackberry10 app, but I can only get it to open an in app browser. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using the org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser plugin which is cross compatible but the default action is to open a new page in the childBrowser window.
If you want to open it in the system browser you have two options:

OPTION 1: use the "_system" target in your call.

Your code will look like this

```
var ref = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');
```

OPTION 2: use the BlackBerry specific "invoke" api.
In order to do so you need to first install the invoke plugin

```
cordova plugin add com.blackberry.invoke
```

Now you can have a function that (using the org.apache.cordova.device plugin) looks like this:

```
function openBlackBerryBrowser(url) {

    function onInvokeSuccess() {
        alert("Invocation successful!");
    }

    function onInvokeError(error) {
       alert("Invocation failed, error: " + error);
    }

    blackberry.invoke.invoke({
        target: "sys.browser",
        uri: url
    }, onInvokeSuccess, onInvokeError);
}

if(window.device.platform.toLowerCase().indexOf('blackberry') > -1) {
    openBlackBerryBrowser('http://www.google.com');
} else {
    var ref = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');
}
```

if you notice I'm setting the target attribute to "sys.browser" which is the default system browser. If the user has different browsers installed you could just specify something different like "com.myapp.mybrowser".