# Worklight API method not working in Blackberry 10

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I am developing an application using IBM Worklight 6.2.

The `WL.App.OpenURL` method is not working in BlackBerry 10 but does work in other environments (iPhone, Android, ...). Likewise, `WL.SimpleDialog` did not work - until the "org.apache.cordova.dialogs" plug-in was added to the project. I had tried adding all of the Cordova plugins but no luck

How to get `WL.App.OpenURL` work in BlackBerry 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why `WL.App.openURL` fails for you, but this method is basically like `window.open`, so what you can do is use `window.open` per the Cordova documentation, here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md

We'll look into whether the API method works or not...

Comment: Hi Idan,
I want do not want to open url inside inAppBrowser having close button on top, I have tired window.open but its not what i am seeking. Same WL.App.OpenURL is opening link in android default browser. please suggest something.

Comment: @rohit, you are not clear; maybe you should explain what you do want.

Comment: I want to open a website URL in BB10 default browser. WL.App.openURL is not working for me on BB10 devices. I have added plugins to my Webworks project at path "MyProject\plugins" also there are default worklight plugins at path "www\webresources\default\worklight\plugins".

Comment: So did you try `window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_system")`, instead? _system means it will use the default browser as opposed to _blank, which should supposedly open the URL in an InAppBrowser.

Comment: You can also try BB's own API for this, see the second option here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833137/open-link-in-external-browser-from-blackberry10-with-cordova

Comment: Hi Idan, 
window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_system") did solved my problem..:) but i am still thinking why? WL.App.openURL is not getting invoked in BB10 even after adding all cordova plugins to my webworks project. If you find something on this please do let me know.:) 
Thanks a Ton!!!!

Comment: Using window.open is perfectly valid. We'll look into WL.App.openURL not working. If your question is now resolved, please accept this answer.

Comment: Hi Idan, Did you found why WL.App.openURL is not working in BB10. Please do revert me on the same.

Comment: Not yet; feel free to open a PMR if you need official IBM support.

Answer (score 1):

WL.App.OpenURL() needs "invoke" plugin to be present in the config.xml.

Verify the config.xml and check if the feature is present. If not, add the plugin using the command -

```
        webworks plugin add com.blackberry.invoke
```

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/v2_2/blackberry.invoke.html

Comment: I had tried adding invoke plugin but still its not working. Also i want use e-mail plugin in my BB10 application, i have already tried my hands on invoke.card plugin but it is not getting triggered i have added feature as follow :-
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" name="blackberry.invoke" value="blackberry.invoke" />
    <feature id="blackberry.app" name="blackberry.app" value="blackberry.app" />
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke.card" name="blackberry.invoke.card" value="blackberry.invoke.card" />

Comment: Hi Rohit,
   Can you please provide the WebWorks SDK details that you used, to build your project.

Comment: BlackBerry WebWorks 2.1.0.13

Comment: Rohit, 
Can you try the steps mentioned in the blog below :

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_blackberry10_project_with_webworks_sdk_2_0?lang=en

Specifically the section "Upgrade Worklight BB10 Project" onwards. This will help you run a BB10 project generated in Worklight studio on WebWorks SDK 2.x

Comment: Vivin, I am doing the same step as given in the link which you have provided but still not able to get WL.App.openURL triggered.
Thanks for your Reply :)

Comment: Hi Vivin, I have also tried adding 'blackberry.app' and 'blackberry.invoke' plugin in my project but its of no help its giving "blackberry.app" undefined. I would appreciate your help on this. :)